# ios Swift - Group separated sprites with syncronized animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, sprite

I am trying to make a synchronized animation (a large video decomposed by frames on separated and smaller puzzle jigsaw parts). This game is a video puzzle. Here is the code I use in three parts by way of example:

```
func Anim_Puzzle13 (Node13 : SKPuzzle) {

    let puzzle13 = SKAction.animateWithTextures(sheet_puzzle13.Puzzle13_(), timePerFrame: 0.066)
    NPuzzle13 = Node13
    NPuzzle13.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(puzzle13))
    NPuzzle13.position = CGPoint(x: 500, y: 400)
    NPuzzle13.zPosition = 1

}

func Anim_Puzzle19 (Node19 : SKPuzzle) {


    let puzzle19 = SKAction.animateWithTextures(sheet_puzzle19.Puzzle19_(), timePerFrame: 0.066)
    NPuzzle19 = Node19
    NPuzzle19.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(puzzle19))
    NPuzzle19.position = CGPoint(x: 600, y: 500)
    NPuzzle19.zPosition = 1

}

func Anim_Puzzle30 (Node30 : SKPuzzle) {


    let puzzle30 = SKAction.animateWithTextures(sheet_puzzle30.Puzzle30_(), timePerFrame: 0.066)
    NPuzzle30 = Node30
    NPuzzle30.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(puzzle30))
    NPuzzle30.position = CGPoint(x: 700, y: 600)
    NPuzzle30.zPosition = 1

}
```

It works well but it does not synchronize between the animations and the video has no integrity. I searched for a long time for a solution to make the animations synchronize; I see two possibilities: first is to create a unique `SKNode()` with all the jigsaw parts inside, but I want to be able to move each jigsaw part independently and have had no success getting a synchronized animation with this method.

The other way seem to be to create a group with all the animations together but this doesn't work, and causes the application to stop.

Here is all the code I use:

```
import SpriteKit
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit
import CoreFoundation

private let kpuzzleNodeName = "puzzle"
private let kdancing = "dancing"


class SKPuzzle: SKSpriteNode {
var name2:String = "";
}

class GameScene: SKScene {



var background = SKVideoNode(videoFileNamed: "Video_Socle.mov")
var selectedNode = SKPuzzle()
var player:AVPlayer?
var videoNode:SKVideoNode?

var NPuzzle13 = SKPuzzle()
var NPuzzle19 = SKPuzzle()
var NPuzzle30 = SKPuzzle()
var NPuzzle11 = SKPuzzle()
var NPuzzle29 = SKPuzzle()
var NPuzzle35 = SKPuzzle()
var puzzle13 = SKAction()
var puzzle19 = SKAction()
var puzzle30 = SKAction()
var puzzle11 = SKAction()
var puzzle29 = SKAction()
var puzzle35 = SKAction()

let sheet_puzzle13 = Puzzle13()
let sheet_puzzle19 = Puzzle19()
let sheet_puzzle30 = Puzzle30()
let sheet_puzzle11 = Puzzle11()
let sheet_puzzle29 = Puzzle29()
let sheet_puzzle35 = Puzzle35()



override init(size: CGSize) {
    super.init(size: size)



    // 1
    self.background.name = kdancing
    self.background.anchorPoint = CGPointZero
    background.zPosition = 0
    self.addChild(background)


    // 2
    let sheet = Statiques()

    let sprite_dancing1 = SKSpriteNode(texture: sheet.Dancing1())
    let sprite_dancing2 = SKSpriteNode(texture: sheet.Dancing2())
    sprite_dancing1.name = kdancing
    sprite_dancing2.name = kdancing


    sprite_dancing1.position = CGPoint(x: 837, y: 752)
    sprite_dancing1.zPosition = 2
    sprite_dancing2.position = CGPoint(x: 1241, y: 752)
    sprite_dancing2.zPosition = 2

    background.addChild(sprite_dancing1)

    background.addChild(sprite_dancing2)



    let imageNames = [sheet.Puzzle13() , sheet.Puzzle19(), sheet.Puzzle30(), sheet.Puzzle11(), sheet.Puzzle29(), sheet.Puzzle35() ]

    for i in 0..<imageNames.count {
        let imageName = imageNames[i]

        let sprite = SKPuzzle(texture: imageName)

        sprite.name = kpuzzleNodeName
        sprite.name2 = "\(i)"

        let offsetFraction = (CGFloat(i) + 1.0)/(CGFloat(imageNames.count) + 1.0)

        sprite.position = CGPoint(x: size.width * offsetFraction, y: size.height / 2)
        sprite.zPosition = 3

        background.addChild(sprite)

    }



}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let positionInScene = touch.locationInNode(self)
        selectNodeForTouch(positionInScene)
    }
}

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    let urlStr = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Video_Socle", ofType: "mov")
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: urlStr!)

    player = AVPlayer(URL: url)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: player!.currentItem, queue: nil)
    { notification in
        let t1 = CMTimeMake(5, 100);
        self.player!.seekToTime(t1)
        self.player!.play()
    }


    videoNode = SKVideoNode(AVPlayer: player!)
    videoNode!.position = CGPointMake(frame.size.width/2, frame.size.height/2)
    videoNode!.size = CGSize(width: 2048, height: 1536)
    videoNode!.zPosition = 0


    background.addChild(videoNode!)
    videoNode!.play()


    let gestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(GameScene.handlePanFrom(_:)))
    self.view!.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
}


func handlePanFrom(recognizer : UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    if recognizer.state == .Began {
        var touchLocation = recognizer.locationInView(recognizer.view)
        touchLocation = self.convertPointFromView(touchLocation)

        self.selectNodeForTouch(touchLocation)
    } else if recognizer.state == .Changed {
        var translation = recognizer.translationInView(recognizer.view!)
        translation = CGPoint(x: translation.x, y: -translation.y)

        self.panForTranslation(translation)

        recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: recognizer.view)
    } else if recognizer.state == .Ended {

    }
}

func degToRad(degree: Double) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(degree / 180.0 * M_PI)
}

func selectNodeForTouch(touchLocation : CGPoint) {
    // 1
    let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(touchLocation)

    if touchedNode is SKPuzzle {
        // 2
        if !selectedNode.isEqual(touchedNode) {
            selectedNode.runAction(SKAction.rotateToAngle(0.0, duration: 0.1))

            selectedNode = touchedNode as! SKPuzzle

            // 3
            if touchedNode.name! == kpuzzleNodeName {
                let sequence = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.rotateByAngle(degToRad(-4.0), duration: 0.1),
                    SKAction.rotateByAngle(0.0, duration: 0.1),
                    SKAction.rotateByAngle(degToRad(4.0), duration: 0.1)])
                selectedNode.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(sequence))
            }
        }
    }
}



func panForTranslation(translation : CGPoint) {
    let position = selectedNode.position

    if selectedNode.name! == kpuzzleNodeName {
        selectedNode.position = CGPoint(x: position.x + translation.x * 2, y: position.y + translation.y * 2)

        print (selectedNode.name)
        print (selectedNode.name2)
        if selectedNode.name2 == "0" {

            Anim_Puzzle13(selectedNode)
        }

        print (selectedNode.name2)
        if selectedNode.name2 == "1" {
            Anim_Puzzle19(selectedNode)
        }

        print (selectedNode.name2)
        if selectedNode.name2 == "2" {
            Anim_Puzzle30(selectedNode)
        }

        print (selectedNode.name2)
        if selectedNode.name2 == "3" {
            Anim_Puzzle11(selectedNode)
        }

        print (selectedNode.name2)
        if selectedNode.name2 == "4" {
            Anim_Puzzle29(selectedNode)
        }

        print (selectedNode.name2)
        if selectedNode.name2 == "5" {
            Anim_Puzzle35(selectedNode)
        }

    }

}


func Anim_Puzzle13 (Node13 : SKPuzzle) {

    let puzzle13 = SKAction.animateWithTextures(sheet_puzzle13.Puzzle13_(), timePerFrame: 0.066)
    NPuzzle13 = Node13
    NPuzzle13.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(puzzle13))
    NPuzzle13.position = CGPoint(x: 500, y: 400)
    NPuzzle13.zPosition = 1

}

func Anim_Puzzle19 (Node19 : SKPuzzle) {


    let puzzle19 = SKAction.animateWithTextures(sheet_puzzle19.Puzzle19_(), timePerFrame: 0.066)
    NPuzzle19 = Node19
    NPuzzle19.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(puzzle19))
    NPuzzle19.position = CGPoint(x: 600, y: 500)
    NPuzzle19.zPosition = 1

}

func Anim_Puzzle30 (Node30 : SKPuzzle) {


    let puzzle30 = SKAction.animateWithTextures(sheet_puzzle30.Puzzle30_(), timePerFrame: 0.066)
    NPuzzle30 = Node30
    NPuzzle30.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(puzzle30))
    NPuzzle30.position = CGPoint(x: 700, y: 600)
    NPuzzle30.zPosition = 1

}

func Anim_Puzzle11 (Node11 : SKPuzzle) {


    let puzzle11 = SKAction.animateWithTextures(sheet_puzzle11.Puzzle11_(), timePerFrame: 0.066)
    NPuzzle11 = Node11
    NPuzzle11.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(puzzle11))
    NPuzzle11.position = CGPoint(x: 800, y: 700)
    NPuzzle11.zPosition = 1

}

func Anim_Puzzle29 (Node29 : SKPuzzle) {


    let puzzle29 = SKAction.animateWithTextures(sheet_puzzle29.Puzzle29_(), timePerFrame: 0.066)
    NPuzzle29 = Node29
    NPuzzle29.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(puzzle29))
    NPuzzle29.position = CGPoint(x: 900, y: 800)
    NPuzzle29.zPosition = 1

}

func Anim_Puzzle35 (Node35 : SKPuzzle) {


    let puzzle35 = SKAction.animateWithTextures(sheet_puzzle35.Puzzle35_(), timePerFrame: 0.066)
    NPuzzle35 = Node35
    NPuzzle35.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(puzzle35))
    NPuzzle35.position = CGPoint(x: 1000, y: 900)
    NPuzzle35.zPosition = 1

}
```

}

I'm not sure if it's possible to synchronize animations like this: with `SKAction()` in several separated parts, because it's necessary to be able to select them individually.

UPDATE: I've tried to follow the action group way but I have the same animation playing on each sprite instead of a different animation synchronized for each sprite (6 different animations synchronized: 6 different sprites):

```
    let sheet13 = Puzzle13()
    let sheet19 = Puzzle19()
    let sheet30 = Puzzle30()
    let sheet11 = Puzzle11()
    let sheet29 = Puzzle29()
    let sheet35 = Puzzle35()

    let imageAnims = [sheet13.Puzzle13_0000() , sheet19.Puzzle19_0000(), sheet30.Puzzle30_0000(), sheet11.Puzzle11_0000(), sheet29.Puzzle29_0000(), sheet35.Puzzle35_0000() ]

    let puzzle13 = SKAction.animateWithTextures(sheet13.Puzzle13_(), timePerFrame: 0.066)
    let puzzle19 = SKAction.animateWithTextures(sheet19.Puzzle19_(), timePerFrame: 0.066)
    let puzzle30 = SKAction.animateWithTextures(sheet30.Puzzle30_(), timePerFrame: 0.066)
    let puzzle11 = SKAction.animateWithTextures(sheet11.Puzzle11_(), timePerFrame: 0.066)
    let puzzle29 = SKAction.animateWithTextures(sheet29.Puzzle29_(), timePerFrame: 0.066)
    let puzzle35 = SKAction.animateWithTextures(sheet35.Puzzle35_(), timePerFrame: 0.066)

    let group = SKAction.group([puzzle13,puzzle19,puzzle30,puzzle11,puzzle29,puzzle35])

    for i in 0..<imageAnims.count {
        let imageAnim = imageAnims[i]

        let spriteAnim = SKPuzzle(texture: imageAnim)

        spriteAnim.name = kanimNodeName
        spriteAnim.name2 = "\(i)"

        let offsetFraction = (CGFloat(i) + 1.0)/(CGFloat(imageAnims.count) + 1.0)

        spriteAnim.position = CGPoint(x: ((size.width)*2) * offsetFraction, y: size.height * 1.5)
        spriteAnim.zPosition = 3

        spriteAnim.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(group))


        background.addChild(spriteAnim)

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I want to list two differents method to create your `SKAction`:

Starting with parallel actions by using `SKAction.group`:

```
let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Spaceship")
let scale = SKAction.scaleTo(0.1, duration: 0.5)
let fade = SKAction.fadeOutWithDuration(0.5)
let group = SKAction.group([scale, fade])
sprite.runAction(group)
```

Another useful method can be the completion , so you can know when an `SKAction` was finished:

```
extension SKNode
{
    func runAction( action: SKAction!, withKey: String!, optionalCompletion: dispatch_block_t? )
    {
        if let completion = optionalCompletion
        {
            let completionAction = SKAction.runBlock( completion )
            let compositeAction = SKAction.sequence([ action, completionAction ])
            runAction( compositeAction, withKey: withKey )
        }
        else
        {
            runAction( action, withKey: withKey )
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
node.runAction(move,withKey:"swipeMove",optionalCompletion: {
   // here the action is finished, do whatever you want
})
```

After that, about your project, I've seen many node.runAction.., you can also adopt this strategy to sinchronize your actions:

```
var myAction30 :SKAction!
var myAction31 :SKAction!

self.myAction30 = SKAction.repeatActionForever(puzzle30)
self.myAction31 = SKAction.repeatActionForever(puzzle31)
let group = SKAction.group([self.myAction30, self.myAction31])
self.runAction(group)
```

**UPDATE**: I've seen your update part, when you speak about "synchronize" probably you don't means the "running in parallel" actions.

So, if you want to run an action after another there is also:

```
self.myAction30 = SKAction.repeatActionForever(puzzle30)
self.myAction31 = SKAction.repeatActionForever(puzzle31)
let sequence = SKAction.sequence([self.myAction30, self.myAction31])
self.runAction(sequence)
```

Comment: I've tried to follow the group action way but all the sprite follow the same animation and not each of them (1 animabtion by sprite, 6 animation in total)

Comment: So , you touch an element, it run for example 6 times, during this running you touch another element and you want this last one is "synchonized" in time with the animation of the first? Have I understand correctly?

Comment: Thanks Alessandro for your help. In fact, I've found a solution. It's to create separately the animated sprite on the scene, to make them hidden and make them appears when the correct sprite is intersecting them. They are correctly synchronized because they have been created exactly at the same time.